# No sound when Ubuntu start up

Tags: 14.04, sound, startup, hdmi

I already set up sound output to HDMI, but when Ubuntu starts up no "drum beats" (startup sound)...
It have sound output normally elsewhere, but no startup sound...
I tried connect headphones to the jack 3.5 port but then I have startup sound, but I need in HDMI no in headphones because I connected them for just a test and TV is what I use...

So, how I get startup sound (the drum beats) when the Ubuntu startup?

My Ubuntu is "Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 LTS"

Comment: Click on the top right icon (gears) then click system settings, then sound.  Is the "HDMI / Displayport" selected?  If not, please select and log off and back on and report back.

Comment: @Fabby Yes, if not how I get others sounds over HDMI like music? and it's not a Mac have not a Displayport, it's a GIADA A51B-BP001

Comment: You should have added that information to your question, then!  ;-)  The drum roll was dropped in 14.04 (you've probably upgraded from 12.04, right?)  I've got a solution for that...  Answer coming up!

Comment: @Fabby no, I din't upgraded from 12.04, and If I select "entrada analogica"/"analogic input" and put headphones i listen the drums when I log in

Comment: Huh???  No clue then!  Answer will be deleted in a few moments...

Comment: Anyone?? This isn't solved yet...

Comment: Answer undeleted...

Comment: @Fabby your anwser is a option but not what i'm looking for, because the drum beats don't dropped in 14.04. But maybe I will use your answer. thanks anyway...

Comment: I know, but that's what I use and it works well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drum-roll login sound was dropped in 14.04.  On the other hand, it's easy to add any log-in sound in 14.04:

1. Go to the dash
2. Open software center
3. Search for `vorbis-tools` and install
4. Go to the dash again
5. Type `startup applications`
6. Click the sole icon remaining
7. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
8. Name= `Desktop login sound`

   Command=`ogg123 /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg`
9. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>
10. Log out
11. Log in

### Done!

Obviously, to have any other log-in sound then the drum-roll, change the file you want to play to something else. (Mine has Majel Barrett saying "Authorisation acknowledged")

Comment: "The drum-roll login sound was dropped in 14.04" not is not, because I have a virtualbox VM with the same Ubuntu and in that machine I listen the drums without the vorbis tools...