# Change Ubuntu 14.04lts start up sound?

Tags: 14.04, sound

On my Ubuntu machine, it no longer makes the drum sound but I was to hook up a custom .ogg sound. How can I do this?  I replaced the name of the file  in the sounds folder of the drums with my custom could,that didn't work. I also made a start launcher on the startup applications app and directed it to the file, nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No sound when Ubuntu start up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583964/no-sound-when-ubuntu-start-up)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the start up sound?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138760/how-do-i-change-the-start-up-sound)

Answer (score 0):

look at the following link:
[Download Mass Effect Composer’s Ubuntu 14.04 Start Up Sounds](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/sam-hulick-ubuntu-start-sound)